# PhpWord y propiedades aplicables

Tags: php, web, phpword

Resulta que tengo mi codigo con las variables a imprimir en el documento de word, pero que sucede, me gustaria saber si se puede aplicar el estilo de fuente solo a una parte de un AddText y a otra parte de la misma agregar otro, por ejemplo negrita un sector y un sector

```
$seccion1->addText('Fecha: ', $fuente_estandar_negrita);
$seccion1->addText($fecha, $fuente_estandar_normal);
```

Asi por ejemplo puede ser, pero quedan en lineas distintas y lo que quiero es que sen mantengan en una misma linea tanto 'Fecha' como $fecha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para cualquiera que pueda leer esto aquí está la solución, resulta que el objetivo de esta pregunta es, encontrar la forma de agregar a distintas palabras estilos diferentes generando un documento de Word con la librería de php phpoffice, específicamente phpword, ¿Cuál es la solución? Pues bien, la solución para asignar distintos estilos a unas palabras y no a todas es usar el método `addTextRun` ¿en qué consiste ese método? en agregar a una variable una "carrera de texto", que pudiese ser mejor entendido como texto corrido. Acá abajo un ejemplo:
De entrada debemos tener nuestra variable dónde "almacenaremos" o instanciaremos la creación de nuestro objeto, osea el documento de Word. En mi caso será documento
``` $documento = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord()`;``
Luego de eso puedes definir información de creación del documento, definir estilos de fuente, entre otras cosas.
Llegamos a la parte importante, debemos agregar una sección para empezar a trabajar en el documento, usaremos nuevamente una variable: ```
$seccion = $documento->addSection();
`A partir de aquí pudieses empezar a trabajar con métodos como addText() el cual requierr dos argumentos, una cadena de texto y un estilo de fuente, ya sea definido anteriormente o en el mismo método, de la forma siguiente`$seccion->addText('Esto es un ejemplo", $fuente_definida);`si no has definido la fuente puedes hacer algo como`$seccion->addText('Esto es un ejemplo', array('name' => 'Arial', 'size' => 12, 'color' => 'black', 'bold' => false));`. Esto puede leerse tan simple como, agregar texto a una sección de nuestro documento con un mismo estilo. Simple, ¿No? Pero, ¿que pasa si no queremos un mismo estilo de fuente para nuestro "texto corrido"? Pues, creamos una nueva variable, en la que almacenaremos nuestro texto corrido en la sección ya creada previamente:`
$parrafo1 = $seccion->addTextRun(['alignment' => 'center', 'lineHeight' => 1]);`el argumento requerido por el método`addTextTun`es solo la configuración de ese texto corrido y párrafo. Y si te preguntas ¿Por qué los estilos del párrafo están definidos distintos que los de la fuentes? ¿Por que en uno usar array() y en el otro usar corchetes []? Pues si estás aquí ya deberías haber pasado por aprender lo fundamental de la programación, sin embargo aún así te lo dire, se trata de dos formas distintas de declarar un arreglo. Y para finalizar usamos el método`addText`dentro de nuestra variable que contiene nuestro textRun o texto corrido y agregamos la cadena de texto que deseemos con su respectivo estilo, en este caso usaré predefinidos ya. Ejemplo:`
parrafo1->addText('Texto con un formato', $estilo_de_fuente_definido);
parrafo1->addText('Segundo texto con formato distinto', $estilo_de_fuente_definido);```
Y así lo logran amigos. De todos modos siempre pueden visitar la documentación oficial y si saben algo de inglés entender de qué trata, https://github.com/PHPOffice sino deja tu comentario acá abajo y si tengo conocimiento te responderé con gusto.

Comment: Excelente!!! Muy util. Con esta respuesta comprendi mucho mejor el funcionamiento de esta parte. Gracias!!!

Comment: De nada hermano, me alegra que le haya servido a alguien.. ✊